# buildpack error deploying node.js app to heroku - files seem to be at the correct level>?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am getting an error in the screen shot bellow deploying a node.js app on heroku saying that the buildpack was unable to detect a node.js codebase

I set the build pack, the package.json is at the root level as is the app.js file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1bg6eir2w93m8a/Screenshot%202020-05-29%2013.44.36.png?dl=0

Not sure what I am doing wrong - thanks!!

Comment: Give a [mre], **as text**, in the question. Take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear:

`A Node.js app on Heroku requires a package.json`.

In the files listed below, you can see that the `package.json` file is missing. You have to commit it and repush your code to Heroku.